# Jasper Report assign a variable value from a DTO to the backcolor tag

Tags: jasper-reports

Is it possible to assign a parameter value or a field value to the "backcolor" tag?

I don't want to set a static color to my conditional style, but I receive the color from Java/database (I can pass it to the report as parameter or as field).

Like this (see backcolor tag):

```
<conditionalStyle>
   <conditionExpression><![CDATA[$P{valutazioneLibretto}.equals("CRITICA")]]></conditionExpression>
   <style mode="Opaque" backcolor=$F{myDTO}.getColor1()/>
</conditionalStyle>
```

Instead of:

```
<style mode="Opaque" backcolor="FF00FF"/>
```

Comment: @AlexK you sent me the feedback? It is not a solution, because I have to use the <propertyExpression> into the <conditionalStyle>, but this is not allowed.

Comment: You don't need conditional style in this. You can do something like this: `<textField>
 <reportElement style="someStyle" x="1" y="1" width="300" height="40">
  <propertyExpression name="net.sf.jasperreports.style.backcolor"><![CDATA[$P{valutazioneLibretto}.equals("CRITICA") ? $F{myDTO}.getColor1() : "#CC0033"]]></propertyExpression>
 </reportElement>
 <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{someText}]]></textFieldExpression>
</textField>`